# Struct->Union-Struct

Tags: visual-c++, struct, unions

I have this struct:

```
struct foo {
   int a;
   union {
      struct {
         int b;
         struct bar
         {
            int c;
            int d;
         } *aBar;
      } in;
   } u;
};
```

How I need to declare a variable of type bar, in Visual C++ ?

Comment: Why the have the union? Or are you planning on extending it later?

Comment: Its a third-party code, i don't make this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an structure like this:

```
struct 
{ 
    int b;  
} in;
```

You are actually creating an object with name `in`, having unnamed-data type. This data-type would be named internally by compiler, and depends on compiler. The style given above does not declare `in` to be a type, but a variable!

If you want to make it a type, use either of given approaches:

```
// Approach 1
struct in{...};

// Approach 2
typedef struct {..} in; // in is now a type, because of `typedef`
```

If you have compiler that supports C++0x, and specifically type `decltype` keyword, you can use it against the first style (which makes `in` a variable). Example:

```
decltype(in) in_var;
in_var.b = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ajay, I solved that way:

```
foo *k;
decltype(k->u.in.aBar) j;
j->c = 1;
j->d = 1;
```